# Is there a way to select all occurences (e.g. regex match) in MULTIPLE files at once to copy these occurences and paste them in a text file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste

I'm looking for a way to extract data from multiple local html files. In Visual Studio Code, it's possible to find/replace in multiple files, but is it also possible to copy from multiple files, or is there an application that can do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From command line ,  you can try grep -ir "searchstring"  from root directory it will give you all occurrences. You can add  -A or -B if you need some lines before or after the search

Comment: Doing this, I get the following message: "grep: warning: recursive search of stdin", also, within my search string, i have several quotation marks ("), maybe that is the problem?

Comment: have you tried the Search Editors, try a Find in a Search Editor

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Or maybe there's an application that can merge multiple files into one file? That would solve the problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I found the "Combine Files" extension for Visual Studio Code. :)